# Determining if Low Power Mode is Enabled/Disabled from Command Line · macOS 12.2.1 (Monterey)

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, battery, system-settings

According to [this article](https://osxdaily.com/2022/03/30/enable-low-power-mode-mac-command-line/) the following script should return the current Power Mode state:

```
pmset -g |grep lowpowermode
```

This is what it actually returns in my case:

[image]

When set through system preferences, the script doesn't seem to change in either Low or High Power mode.

Doesn't change neither if the script is:

```
pmset -g |grep highpowermode
```

**Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: I see MBP in there, but what exact model of Mac is it?

Answer (score 1):

First note that while your picture looks correctly-entered, the line appearing in your question has "**high**powermode" printed which, to my knowledge, is not one of the management settings entries.

Next, about grep; in the form used in that article, `grep` just filters down the output piped `|` to it from the first command, to include only lines containing `lowpowermode` …and you apparently don't have any. So, grep is just filtering out everything. You can instead read through all the power settings—the complete output of the first command—by just entering:

```
pmset -g
```

We don't have the complete picture yet, but my guess is that your Mac model does not fully support the new lowpowermode, so pmset doesn't include a setting for it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what your command returns for me: https://pastebin.com/VTwMqhL8
My MacBook it's advertised as supporting that power mode. 
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)
https://gadgets360.com/laptops/news/apple-16-inch-macbook-pro-2021-m1-max-high-power-mode-turbo-performance-boost-2584303
So I am surprised by your statement